# Terraform Root Level output issue

Tags: terraform

I am having some weird issues with module root level outputs in terraform.

We have the following in outputs.tf at the root level:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```

And in the module itself we have

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags {
      Name = "${upper(var.env)}-TF"
      env = "${var.env}"
      managed = "Terraform"
  }
}
```

However when running a plan terraform errors out parsing the output block and says with trace on:

```
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.8.0  142dd256ad48ab17b6019fe9cd18712167fcf4b4
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/usr/local/bin/terraform", "get"}
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [DEBUG] Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [DEBUG] Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /root/.terraformrc
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
Get: file:///srv/terraform/modules/networking/
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [DEBUG] Detected home directory from env var: /root
Error loading Terraform: module root: 1 error(s) occurred:

* output 'vpc_id': unknown resource 'aws_vpc.vpc' referenced in variable aws_vpc.vpc.id
2017/01/31 17:56:54 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
```

I'm at a loss at this point. I have looked everywhere and nowhere have I found anything that even hits as to why we'd be getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, The issue here is this:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```

When defining root level outputs you need to do it this way:

```
output "vpc_id_root" {
  value = "${module.networking.vpc_id}"
}
```

Comment: You also need a `vpc_id` output in the module to pass it out to the root context.